# python platform.uname() - strange results for win11

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, windows-11

I would expect when I run `platform.uname()` I would recieve release == 11, but it is 10.

Can someone tell, why?

within that, what actually is a node?

with win 11, python 3.7 executing:

```
import platform
x = platform.uname()

x == (
  system='Windows',
  node='w11fi',   # what is a node?
  release='10',   # Supposed to be 11?
  version='10.0.22000',
  machine='AMD64',
  processor='Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel')
```

Answer (score 3):

It's confusing, but, according to [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91025#issuecomment-1093945698) and [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11_version_history#Version_history), what you're seeing is correct:

> The major.minor version of Windows 11 is 10.0. The build number for Windows 11 is 22000 and above.

Much more detail in the following cpython issues:

- [issue 91025](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91025)
- [issue 89545](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89545)